# Duda con Diccionario y combobox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, diccionarios

Buenas estoy tratando de conseguir un valor en un diccionario dependiendo de la selección de un combobox, pero no esta funcionando.

defino el diccionario de esta forma:

```
dic_frec = {'Semanal':'1   wk', 'Quincenal': '2   wk','Mensual': '1   mo','Bimensual': '2   mo','Trimestral': '3   mo','Cuatrimestral': '4   mo','Semestral': '6   mo','Anual': '1   y (365 days)','Bianual': '2   y (365 days)','Trianual': '3   y (365 days)','Quinquenal': '5   y (365 days)','Decenal': '10   y (365 days)'}
```

luego el combobox de esta forma:

```
    frec=StringVar()
    combo1 = ttk.Combobox(self.raiz, state="readonly", textvariable=frec)
    combo1["values"] = ["Semanal", "Quincenal", "Mensual", "Bimensual", "Trimestral", "Cuatrimestral", "Semestral", "Anual", "Bianual", "Trianual", "Quinquenal", "Decenal"]
    combo1.grid(padx=5, pady=5, column=1, row=1)
```

ahora, cuando hago los siguientes print

```
print(frec.get()) #obtengo Semanal
frecuencia = dic_frec.get('Semanal') # coloco un valor fijo
print(frecuencia) #obtengo 1   wk, que es el resultado que espero
```

pero si hago

```
frecuencia = dic_frec.get(frec.get()) # obtengo None.
```

No estaria viendo el error.

Comment: Podrías poner el código completo por favor? Intenté hacer mi propio programa de tkinter con pedasos de lo que pasaste y a mi me funciona perfecto... Sospecho que el problema está en una parte del código que no estás mostrando.

Comment: Hice unas ligeras modificaciones al código para poder ejecutarlo. Luego reemplacé la parte donde usas la funcion busqueda por el método "correcto". Resulta que funciona perfectamente. Es un error muy extraño el que tienes.